# Responsive 3 column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, responsive

I would like my 3 columns to be responsive on mobile devices and I have trouble doing it.  What do I add to it, or how do I make it work? :) I know it might be a silly question, but I am supper beginner, trying to learn. Thank you

This is the code im using:

```html
<ul style="-webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; column-gap: 310px;">
    <li>
       <p>aaa</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>bbb</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>ccc</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>ddd</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>eee</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>fff</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>ggg</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>hhh</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p>iii</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: more details please, do you have a design or something? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung Sorry, yes, here is my design: https://imgur.com/a/LjeTybG

Comment: responsive ? do you mean it should turn into 2 col or only one if window is too small?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I dont have a preference, but probably one if I had to choose :) Either way is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint From your comment

> @G-Cyrillus I dont have a preference, but probably one if I had to choose :) Either way is fine

You could use `column-width` instead `column-count` and eventually `clamp()` sizing it :

```css
li {border:1px solid;margin-bottom:2px}
```

```html
<ul style=" column-width: clamp(310px, 30vw, 800px); ">
  <li>
    <p>aaa</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>bbb</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ccc</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>eee</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>fff</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ggg</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>hhh</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>iii</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

About `clamp()` , see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

About `column-width` see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width

Comment: Thank you, although i dont know if i uderstand it correctly :)) https://imgur.com/a/LjeTybG I have three columns and three rows at first, just like on the printscreen and then when the screen gets smaller, ideally have one column with 9 rowns

Comment: @Szimona or i probably did not understand your question and comment ;)

Comment: Its possible that i didnt write it correctly, i edited my first comment to you, thank you :)

Comment: @Szimona okay, the snippet here will show 9 rows (1col) if the window is less than average 650px , 5rows (2col) if the window is less than average 1015px , 3rows(3col) if less than average 2450px. columns are then stretch to fill avalaible space (border and margin on li is to let you see how it behaves while resizing the window) run snippet in full page, then resize window to check the behavior. Let us know if that is or not what you looked for ;)

Comment: thanks, now bare with me please because i might have some silly questions :D 1. Do i have to use the:     li {border:1px solid;margin-bottom:2px} since i dont need boxes? 2., When i dont use it (li {border:1px solid;margin-bottom:2px}) the rows are not in a same line - https://imgur.com/a/zFc59F7

Comment: I tried to use the code you gave but when I saved it, on the computer screen it showed me one column, and as i was making it smaller, it turned into three :D I need it the other way around

Comment: @Szimona You probably did something weird because column-width on its own cannot do what you described. Did you removed every other style or did you just copy/paste the CSS inside your your style sheet hoping it would work ?

Comment: I removed everything and added yours :) I have this code in right now: https://imgur.com/a/09A7FYZ, which seems to work, but when i space out the columns with  column-gap: 310px it stops to be responsive :/ I need the columns to space out on the page like it is shown https://imgur.com/a/12ucir8

Comment: why do you need those 310px ? display:grid and column-width are not compatible, use one or the other, but grid will follow the given template: 3 column anytime as i can see

Comment: Oh, i see, I did not know, I tried to push/space out the columns, so the last column is in line with the sentence above. Right now it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/12ucir8 but i need to move them where the arrows point. I. appreciate your help, really :)

Comment: Look, i used your code, i added it: https://imgur.com/a/yBDKCe7, looks good in preview: https://imgur.com/a/xA72FVv, but on the page itself is one column: https://imgur.com/a/3kmCeqe

Comment: @Szimona No idea if you solved yet your issue, but from screens , there is nothing i can see about the whole CSS code you have. If the snippets works and not your copy/paste, there then is either a typo or other CSS involved for that UL than you do not tell us or did not noticed. ;) added : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width to the answer in case you are misusing it.

Comment: Thank you, you are very nice to reply, I have not solved it unfortunately. Now im thinking, that when the screen is smaller, i would like to have one column, like with the code you suggested, but now i am more confused than ever :D Hopefully somehow i will able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid, it is imao more clear solution:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 3; grid-template-columns: 3">

  <p>Skvělé produkty</p>
  <p>Rychlé doručení</p>
  <p>Ochotu</p>
  
  <p style="grid-row: 2">Přívětivé ceny</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 2">Výhodné dopravné</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 2">Spolehlivost</p>

  <p style="grid-row: 3">Bleskovou expedici</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 3">Férový obchod</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 3">Bezodkladnou reklamaci</p>

</div>
```

Edit: Examples from chat:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 2; grid-template-columns: 3">

  <li>Skvělé produkty</li>
  <li>Rychlé doručení</li>
  <li>Ochotu</li>
  
  <li style="grid-row: 2">Skvělé produkty 2</li>
  <li style="grid-row: 2">Rychlé doručení 2</li>
  <li style="grid-row: 2">Ochotu 2</li>

</div>
```

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 2; grid-template-columns: 3">

  <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Skvělé produkty</p>
  <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Rychlé doručení</p>
  <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Ochotu</p>
  
  <p style="grid-row: 2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Přívětivé ceny</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Výhodné dopravné</p>
  <p style="grid-row: 2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGGj.png" style="vertical-align: middle">Spolehlivost</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you? How would it work if I had 3 rows and 3 columns?

Comment: How do you mean that? In my answer, there are 3 rows and 3 columns...

Comment: I see it now, thank you, appreciate it :) Also can I use the <li> since i need this little logos in the front of each list item https://imgur.com/a/SmDHmxo

Comment: Of course. you can use `<li>` tags instead of `<p>`. It will work good. You can also insert a picture (best svg) with your icon before text (= at the beginning of `<p>` tag)

Comment: I tried it again and it works, thank you but now the last column is notat the end of the page https://imgur.com/a/12ucir8 I tried to use column-gap: 310px; like before but it does not seem to work, why is that? :)

Comment: I mean it works on a desktop the column-gap: 310px, but not on mobile :/

Answer (score 0):

The are some ways to make a responsive web design. But i think using css @media is easy to use

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Media responsive</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .left,
    .right {
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    .left {
      background: blue;
      float: left;
      width: 60%;
    }
    
    .right {
      background: red;
      float: right;
      width: 40%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you see above, I create 2 elements float 2 sides. But when using small screen (<768px) you will see it turn into 1 line

You can read more here: [W3 Responsive Web](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
Something keeps in mind:

1. Consider use rem, vh,vw, em instead of px because it like % and suitable to responsive
2. Always add meta viewport